# Load testing WCF service hosted in local IIS using JMeter

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, jmeter, load-testing

My requirement is to load test a WCF service hosted in the local IIS server. We are trying to improve the performance of a WCF service. In the PROD environment both the WCF service and the desktop application which consumes this service also resides in the same machine.

So in order to baseline the existing performance of the WCF serrvice, I'm trying to use JMeter to load-test the service by running it from the same machine where the service is hosted.

I'm using JMeter's HTTP Test Script Recorder to capture any request going from desktop app to WCF service, so that I will be able to later increase the thread count to get the performance measurements.

problem is I'm unable to capture any requests going to the service hosted in the local IIS server. But if I host the same service in a separate server and execute the Jmeter from the machine where consuming desktop app is running, then Jmeter is able to capture all the outgoing requests to that web server.

> Is that even possible to record requests where service and consuming
>   desktop app both resides in the same machine?

### **Current Configurations**

***I'm using 8895 as the port number in the Jmeter proxy***

[image]

***Manual proxy setting in windows (using the same port number configured in Jmeter)***

[image]

***Desktop app configuration file (which sends requests to local service)***

```
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IPayment" proxyAddress="http://127.0.0.1:8895" useDefaultWebProxy="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false">                     
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>            
        </wsHttpBinding>        
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <!--<endpoint address="http://10.2.179.100/PaymentService/Payment.svc " binding="wsHttpBinding"-->                      
      <endpoint address="http://127.0.0.1:88/Payment.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"          
          bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IPayment" contract="PaymentServiceReference.IPayment"
            name="WSHttpBinding_IPayment" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You might need to add [Microsoft Loopback Adapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/cc708322(v=ws.10)) in order to capture link-local traffic

   [image]
2. You might need to set a [system-level HTTP proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/microsoft-defender-atp/configure-proxy-internet) like:

   ```
   netsh winhttp set proxy 127.0.0.1:8895
   ```

More information: [How to Run Performance Tests of Desktop Applications Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-desktop-applications-using-jmeter/)

Comment: Thank you for your input, I will try your approach and see if the requests are being captured in Jmeter.

Comment: Really appreciate your help,finally I got it working. In addition to what you have suggested, I also had to use the IPv4 of my local machine in the desktop app's app.config file (WCF endpoint address) having localhost or 127.0.0.1 didn't work.